# Need help creating an equation in C++ to calculate total

Tags: c++

My updated code. When I run the code it keeps outputting the prices of all the packages instead of just the one I ask for.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

// to keep it simple
int choice_a = 995;
int choice_b = 1995;
int choice_c = 3995;
char choice;
int message_units, x=1;
double price;
bool selected = false;

// this loop shows the options initially
do {
cout << "Which package do you choose (enter A, B or C)" << endl;
// you will need to check this
cin >> choice;
// keeping it simple
if (choice == 'A') { price = choice_a; selected = true; }
else if (choice == 'B') { price = choice_b; selected = true; }
else if (choice == 'C') { price = choice_c; selected = true; }
cout << endl;
}
// loops until something was selected
while (selected == false);

do{
cout << "How many message units (enter 1 - 672)" << endl;
// again check this
cin >> message_units;
x++;
}
while(x<2);

if(message_units > 5){
choice_a += 100 * (message_units - 5);
}
cout << "Your total cost is " << choice_a /100 << "." <<choice_a%100 endl
if(message_units > 15){
  choice_b += 50 * (message_units - 15);
 }
cout <<"Yourtotalcostis"<<choice_b /100 << "." << choice_b%100<<endl;
```

Comment: I see a lot of errors in it, I don't think any of those while loops are necessary.

Comment: A, B and C have nothing to do with this problem. If you correct the capitalization in your question, I'll show you how to calculate the price of the package.

Comment: I am in the process of writing some code in the right direction.

Comment: in the directions for the assignment the packages are called a, b, and c.

Comment: @ eric my instructor said I need a loop for when getting the number of message units and for which package they chose.

Comment: @ Beta the capitalization is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

(You missed an "i" or two, but English is difficult for a non-native speaker.)

```
Atotalcost = 9.95;
if(messageunits>5)
  Atotalcost += 1.0 * (messageunits-5);
```

**EDIT:**

There are several ways to deal with amounts of money. One of them is to store an amount as a number of cents, then print it out with care. For example, the amount $2.34 is stored as `int price = 234`, then to print it out we print `price/100` (which is 2), then a decimal point, then `price%100` (which is 34, the '%' is the modulo operator, you can look it up). So the code will look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int messageunits;
  cout << "how many message units(enter 1 - 672)" << endl;
  cin >> messageunits;

  int Atotalcost = 995; // cost of package a, in cents
  if(messageunits > 5){
    Atotalcost += 100 * (messageunits - 5);
  }

  cout << "Your total cost is " << Atotalcost/100 << "." << Atotalcost%100 << endl;
}
```

There is still much work to do, but this is a good start.

Comment: When i ran the code it said Atotalcost does not have a name type?

Comment: @user4954919: I notice now that you declared `Atotalcost` as `int`. Do you want it to be the integer number of cents (e.g. 995), or the non-integer number of dollars (e.g. 9.95)? And are you familiar with non-integer numeric types like `float`?

Comment: I heard of float but never used it. Yes the price needs to be 9.95 with decimals. I ran this code if(messageunits>5)
 Atotalcost = a += 1.0 * (messageunits-5);
 cout <<"Your total is " << Atotalcost << endl;
 }
and got 98 when I put 6 message units in.

Comment: Ok I have done the math correctly for all three packages, but when i run the program it gives me the total cost for all three packages instead of the just the one i asked for how do i change this? I updated my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here is the new code I put in.   Atotalcost = 995; // cost of package a, in cents
  if(messageunits > 5){
    Atotalcost += 100 * (messageunits - 5);
  }

  cout << "Your total cost is " << Atotalcost/100 << "." << Atotalcost%100 << endl;

Btotalcost = 1995;
 if(messageunits > 15){
  Btotalcost += 50 * (messageunits - 15);
  }
  
  cout << "Your total cost is " << Btotalcost/100 << "." << Btotalcost%100 << endl; // two total costs?

Ctotalcost = 3995;
 cout << "Your total cost is " << Ctotalcost/100 << "." << Ctotalcost%100 << endl;

Comment: @user4954919: Your branching is incorrect. Remove all of the code dealing with `messageunits` and numbers, and try to get the code to print different things for the different plans. When it works, put the price code back in.

Comment: If you could get me started i would appreciate it. I think i need some if statements but not sure how i would write it so it only ouputs the price I ask for a particular package. This project is wearing me out man.

Comment: @user4954919 `int main(){char plan='a'; if(plan=='a'){cout << "plan A" << endl;} if(plan=='b'){cout << "plan B" << endl;} return 0;}`

Comment: Ok does that to be in my loop or after?

Comment: @user4954919: You have to do some of the work yourself, or there's no point.

Comment: @user4954919: I don't know whether the fault lies in your text, your teacher or your background skills, but you're asking for more help than this site is designed to provide. Hire a tutor; I'm sure you can find one who charges less per hour than I do.

Answer (score 0):

Along those lines, this example may have a few minor errors and I tried to keep it simple.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
bool finished = false;



do {

    // to keep it simple
    double choice_a = 9.95;
    double choice_b = 19.95;
    double choice_c = 39.95;
    char choice;
    int message_units;
    double price;
    bool selected = false;





    // this loop shows the options initially
    do {
        cout << "Which package do you choose (enter A, B or C)" << endl;
        // you will need to check this
        cin >> choice
        // keeping it simple
        if (choice == 'A') { price = choice_a; selected = true; }
        else if (choice == 'B') { price = choice_b; selected = true; }
        else if (choice == 'C') { price = choice_c; selected = true; }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // loops until something was selected
    while (selected == false);






    // user enters how many units is wanted
    cout << "How many message units (enter 1 - 999)" << endl;
    // again check this (if homework requires checking input)
    cin >> message_units;

    // Calculating message units
    if (message_units > 5) price += message_units * 1;
    else price += message_units * 2; // if $2.00 normal?



    // Total Price Output
    cout << "Total: " << price << endl;



    // Is user done?
    char done;
    cout << "Do you want to enter another? press enter to continue. If you are done, type something and press enter.";
    cin >> done;

    // check
    if (done != '') {
        finished = true;
    }
} 
while (finished = false);
```

Alright, that is about it. Two do while loops and the rest. There may be some slight errors while compiling, really, you should try to fix those yourself as this is pretty much the entire assignment...

Comment: I appreciate your help, but like I said in my earlier comment my teacher said i needed two loops for the message units and the choice. He said the code has to be ran at least once which is why i did the do while loop.

Comment: @user4954919 aight, I added a while loop to the first part (where the user enters A B or C. It will loop until the user enters a valid entry.) You would do something like that to check the user entered a valid message unit (a number.)

Comment: my teacher specifically said we needed a do while loop. how would I change yours to a do while. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Aight, updated the code. The second loop should be in similar fashion. If you have issues with my code, attempt it if still need help, Ill update.

Comment: How can I show you my updated code? I have a question for you.

Comment: Its updated. When I run the code it keeps outputting the prices of all the packages instead of just the one I ask for?

Comment: Did you figure it out? Ive tried everything and it still doesn't output only the price I ask for.

Comment: @user4954919 alright, I finished it, there may be some minor compile errors but once fixed. this will work.

Comment: No its half the assignment still have more to do but thanks for the help. This is my first c++ class.